# jsp не видит атрибуты

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Изучаю Web разработку на java, в качесте источника использую это видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSF4U5K0nto,

все делаю точно так же как говорит автор, если вкратце, создаю сервлет в котором есть такой метод

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.getSession().setAttribute("posts", DAO.getPosts()); // (static public List<Post> getPosts()) передаю лист с тремя экземплярами класса Post 
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/posts.jsp").forward(request,response);

}
```

В итоге этот кусок jsp файла

```
<table border="1">
  <c:forEach items="${posts}" var="post">
    <tr>
      <td>${post.id}</td>
      <td>${post.txt}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

должен получить лист (`items = "${posts}"`), но в моем случае ничего не приходит и таблица получается пустой. Пытался задавать другие атрибуты, например с типом String jsp все равно ничего не видит.

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/52Br/NFRr1iGJt - мой сохранный проект

Answer (score 1):

Вы не подключили библиотеку, обрабатывающую Ваши теги наподобие `<c:forEach >`.
Добавьте в каждый Ваш JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

и всё заработает.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень помогли мне, а я пересмотрел видео и заметил, что там была эта строка, но каким то образом я ее пропустил.